# Can not find iOS automation API documents

Tags: ios, automation

I want to learn more about iOS automation API when using XCODE's Instruments. I searched a lot but found the website "https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/" is invalid now. Does anybody know the correct url for iOS automation API documents?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you can go for **[XCTest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest)**

`XCUITestClass` provides you UI automation from Recording feature.

It also covers :

> A. Functionality test automation.
>
> B. UI test automation..

*Update*: Developer documentation for [Automation Instruments.](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=automation%20instrument)

> C. Performance test automation.

Comment: This may be a good choice. But where could I find API documents for automation in Instruments?

Comment: Hi, This link might help you : https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=automation%20instrument